# Why there exist definite integral for a constant function $f(x)$?

Tags: definite-integrals

For a proof of a existence of definite integral for a monotone function it is noted that if a function is a constant then it has a definite integral. Why?

Comment: Apply the definition and note how simple the terms are because $f$ is constant.

Comment: Perhaps *definitive* -> *definite* ?

Comment: Surely a constant is definitively monotone?

Comment: Darboux sums work trivially.